# Условие для уникальности вводимых данных

Tags: python, django

мне нужно чтоб фио сотрудников не совпадали. и чтоб ошибка возникала после попытки сохраняить изменения, если 2 раза указали одного и того же человека.

```py
  class JrtnPerson(models.Model):
    rtn = models.ForeignKey(Drtn, verbose_name='Подразделение Ростехнадзора', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя и Отчество')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_mob = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона мобильный", blank=True, null=True)
    tel_rab = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона рабочий", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Электронная почта", blank=True, null=True)
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return '%s %s' % (self.surname, self.name)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.JrtnPerson.objects.filter(surname=self.surname, name=self.name).exists():
            super(surname,name,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: удалять выбраный продукт из исходного списка

Comment: Вы получили исходный список, когда пользователь выбрал продук, положите его в другой список "выранных", а из списка доступных удалите. Либо, если список это список словарей, то выбранный товар можно маркировать как `isSelected: true` и выдавать пользователю для повторного выбора отфильтрованный список по `isSelected == false`. Покажите ваш код и тогда можно будет дать более точный ответ

Comment: надо на код смотреть, как выглядит модель => можно указать поле модели как ´unique=True´ и это решает большую часть связанных я этим задач